# Standard deviation vs. variance as a feature

Tags: machine-learning, variance, standard-deviation, feature-engineering

I'm using the median of response times (of users) as a feature in a machine learning context. As a second feature I want to use the standard deviation or variance of the response times. Of course, the variance is just the squared standard deviation, so from that point of view I think it should not matter which I choose.

Does it really not matter if choosing the standard deviation or the variance?

Comment: To answer your question: yes it does matter. To answer your next question "why?": depends on the learning algorithm.

Comment: What are you trying to predict? Whenever I hear of people using a group mean as a predictor, my thought is to recommend a multilevel model, which will allow you to use all your data without resorting to summaries.

Comment: A note on your decision: Maybe the _variation coefficient_ might be the compromise of what you try to achieve (be aware that this coefficient needs a ratio scale).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try both and see which one improves your model fit. Alternatively, you can check the correlation coefficients with the dependent (target) variable for both (standard deviation and variance) features, and keep the one that has the higher correlation coefficient. In general, I like the standard deviation more because it has the same scale (units of measurement) as the mean/median values, while the variance does not.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very valid and relevant, because both measures represent your features in a different way. Thus, there has to be put some thought in what you want to express with the feature deriving from your domain knowledge. The variance is not " ***just*** " the squared standard deviation like you state, it comes with the effect of valuing higher deviations more and leveling deviations `-1 > x < 1`.

See e.g.:

```
Standard Deviation in revenues (€) | Variance
---------------------------------------------
                            3.0 €  | 9.0
                            2.0 €  | 4.0
                           -0.3 €  | -0.09
                            0.1 €  | 0.01
```

As you can see the variance grants higher deviations (due to its exponential nature) a higher value and decreases the effect of minor deviations `-1 > x < 1`.

Therefore, if you want a feature expressing that higher deviations are worse than minor ones the variance might be a better choice. On the other hand, if this overstates deviations in your context standard deviation might be the better feature.

Still, @Vishals hint to try both still holds - Sometimes try and error cannot be wrong as well.